# Picking a random font from UIFont

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uilabel, uifont

How can I pick a random `UIFont` by name (with a constant size)?

There isn't much more to this question but it seems SO wants more from me so here is some meaningless twaddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create an array of all the fonts you want and then use arc4rand to pick a random object at index to use as your font.

Comment: I want all of the fonts - there are quite a few (http://iosfonts.com). Was hoping there is some crafty way to pull a list from UIFont.

Comment: UIFont has these class methods "familyNames:" & "fontNamesForFamilyName:familyName:". these return arrays of the info requested. do you need more info on how to use these or is that enough?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
extension UIFont {
static var random: UIFont {
    return UIFont(name: UIFont.familyNames.randomElement()!, size: CGFloat.random(in: 5...15))!
}
```

}

Then use this extension as usual:

```
let font = UIFont.random
```

This gives a fully random font with random size (you can of course eliminate this feature if it is not needed)